# Extract subject, predicate, object from RDF N-Triples file

Tags: rdf, export-to-csv

How can I extract subject, predicate, object from RDF file of N-Triples format and save in CSV file?

Comment: Bit broad and vague this. Why do you need this? What programming language / tool should this happen in? What have you tried sofar and where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually, I want to extract subject, predicate, object from any format of RDF file into three columns of a triples table. For example, the columns values for subject, predicate, object will be ID1, Type, Book respectively.

Comment: I see. Please [edit] your question to reflect this: make your question as concrete and specific as possible. Also don't forget to include what you've tried so far and what language this should (preferably) happen in. Lastly: have a look at [ask] for tips on how to ask good questions - using those tips now and in the future will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple conversion would just do a global search and replace on your N-Triples file, introducing commas in the right places, and removing the full stop at the end of each line.

However, there are several problems with this: RDF values may contain commas, and Literal values can have a datatype (`^^xsd:int`) or a language tag (`@en`) attached. Depending on what you want to use the CSV for, you will need to escape this value somehow.

Possibly the simplest way is to put the entire thing in quotes and escape all occurrences of commas and quotes, so:

```
"a literal, like, string"@en
```

becomes:

```
"\"a literal\, like\, string\"@en"
```

Given all this, you can either work some regular expression magic in a text editor ([vim](http://www.vim.org/) is a good choice for this), or you can write a simple program to convert your file. For example, using Java and [RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/), you could convert your file using something like this:

```java
FileInputStream ntriples = new FileInputStream("...");
Model rdf = Rio.parse(ntriples, "", RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);

try (FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(...)) {
   for (Statement st: rdf) {
      csvWriter.write(convert(st.getSubject()));
      csvWriter.write(", ");

      csvWriter.write(convert(st.getPredicate()));
      csvWriter.write(", ");

      csvWriter.write(convert(st.getObject()));
      csvWriter.write("\n");
   }
}
```

... where the `convert` method does the necessary magic to convert an `IRI`, a `BNode` or a `Literal` to an adequately quoted and escaped String value - you should be able to work that out for yourself given what I've mentioned above. Added benefit of this approach is that it works not just for N-Triples, but for any type of RDF syntax that Rio has a parser for.

You could also try to use a CSV parsing/writing library, like opencsv, or jackson-dataformat-csv. As said: the options are endless.

Comment: Thanks Jeen. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I am getting an error when I am writing the statement "Model rdf = Rio.parse(ntriples, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);". The method parse(InputStream, String, RDFFormat, Resource...) in the type Rio is not applicable for the arguments (File, RDFFormat)

Comment: Ah, minor mistake in my code sample. Fixed now. For future reference you can find the RDF4J documentation (including API Javadoc and examples) at http://docs.rdf4j.org/ .

Comment: Now I am getting: The method parse(InputStream, String, RDFFormat, Resource...) in the type Rio is not applicable for the arguments (File, String, RDFFormat).

Comment: You need to change the File to a FileInputStream.

Comment: Could you please guide me to write convert method to extract subject, predicate, and object from N-Triples file.

Comment: @Mahmud, tell you what: why don't you give it a go yourself first, and then if you run into problems, post a followup question where you show what you've tried sofar and where you're stuck.